# get unicode error when print in html flask

Tags: unicode, flask

Getting unnicode error when print in html Flask. 
Here is my code.

```
{% if(backpaths) %}
{%   for n in backpaths:%}
{%      print '%s'%n %}
</br>
{%   endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I tried to use n.decode('utf-8') but it didn't work and got same error

`backpaths` is set to:

```
['1\xe6\x9c\x89 --(HYPER)--> quantifier={indefinite|\xe4\xb8\x8d\xe5\xae\x9a\xe6\x8c\x87} --(HYPO)--> \xe6\x9c\x89 ', '2\xe6\x9c\x89 --(HYPER)--> exist|\xe5\xad\x98\xe5\x9c\xa8 --(HYPO)--> \xe6\x9c\x89 ']
```

here is the traceback

```
(most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ganchimeg/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/__init__.py", line 125, in homepage
    return render_template('index.html', backpaths=successPaths)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 128, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 110, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 969, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 742, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ganchimeg/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/templates/index.html", line 31, in top-level template code
    {{      n }}
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: There is no `print` in Jinja. Just use `{{ n }}` to include the value in your template there.

Comment: And if you get errors, give us the full traceback.

Comment: ok. but still getting same error when use {{  n }}

Comment: Then *share that error*. What kind of data do you have in `backpaths`? Are they byte strings perhaps?

Comment: if print backpaths in python it will looks like this

Comment: Total path from 有///拿 to 有: 5
['1\xe6\x9c\x89 --(HYPER)--> quantifier={indefinite|\xe4\xb8\x8d\xe5\xae\x9a\xe6\x8c\x87} --(HYPO)--> \xe6\x9c\x89 ', '2\xe6\x9c\x89 --(HYPER)--> exist|\xe5\xad\x98\xe5\x9c\xa8 --(HYPO)--> \xe6\x9c\x89 ']

Comment: You don't have unicode values, you have byte strings. **decode** those.

Comment: Your traceback doesn't match the code you said gave the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have Unicode strings, you have *byte strings*. Python tries to implicitly decode those using the standard ASCII codec. Explicitly decode them:

```
{% if(backpaths) %}
{%   for n in backpaths:%}
{{       n.decode('utf8') }}
</br>
{%   endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

It'll be better if you passed in `backpaths` into the template ready-decoded.

Comment: @GanchimegL: I doubt it'll be the *exact same error*. Are you sure you still get a decode error for ASCII when you are now decoding as UTF-8?

Comment: you're right. I don't have to unicode strings. I fixed it.